# How to make bulleted list in swing in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, bulletedlist

In my application, I'd like to create a bullet ed list of data in a label.  How can i do this?

When i searched, I found Styled Text bullet ed list with SWT. How can i do the same with Swing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap you `String` in a `html` tag and build away...

[image: Bullet List]

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html><ul>" +
        "<li>Bananas are yellow</li>" +             
        "<li>Oranges are orange</li>" + 
        "<li>Strewberries are red</li>" + 
        "</ul><html>");
```

---

> How to give events to these items in label

Given the fact that wasn't part of your original question, that changes the answer, instead, you should be using something like a series of `JRadioButton`s, see [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Radio buttons and check boxes

[image: RadioButtons][image: CheckBox]

Comment: How to give events to these items in label

Comment: Given the fact that wasn't part of your original question, that changes the answer, instead, you should be using something like a series of `JRadioButton`s, see [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)